# How do I make a commit is not in the master branch with git-worktree

Tags: git, github, commit, git-worktree

I have a repository with name "Name" for example. And in the repository has two branches:

- master
- gh-pages

If I have made changes to the folder "Name", the commands I get the commit:

```
$ git worktree add ../Name-gh-pages gh-pages
```

With this command, I get two directories:

- "Name" with files from "master" branch
- "Name-gh-pages" with files from "gh-pages" branch

If I have made changes to the folder "Name", the commands I get the commit:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "test"
```

How do I commit if I make changes to a folder "Name-gh-pages"? Command "git add ." sees the changes only in the folder "Name". Command "git checkout gh-pages" is not working in this case.

**Update.** jibe suggested solution.

```
$ git worktree add ../Name-gh-pages gh-pages
```

We now have two working directory.

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "test"
$ git push
```

We've committed to the "master" branch.

```
$ cd ..
$ cd Name-gh-pages
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "test gh-pages"
$ git push
```

We've committed to the "gh-pages" branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you indicated it, `$ git worktree add ../Name-gh-pages gh-pages` your modification on gh-pages are tracked on `Name-gh-pages` folder. You should simply go in `Name-gh-pages` and then you will be able to make modification, commit and push. But you cannot have 2 linked repositories tracking the same branch that is why you cannot checkout gh-pages from `Name` folder.